# What does "fleet aside" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "so badly that even improvements in 2019 couldn't save Reebok" ?

Some of that percentage drop has stemmed from the namesake Adidas brand’s healthier growth. Still, it’s hard to deny that Reebok has been flailing for too long, **fleeting improvements in 2019 aside**.

Source: Some of that percentage drop has stemmed from the namesake Adidas brand’s healthier growth. Still, it’s hard to deny that Reebok has been flailing for too long, fleeting improvements in 2019 aside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“fleeting” here means that the improvements in 2019 were temporary.

“X aside” means X is a notable exception but didn’t affect the overall performance.